# What does ところ do here?

Tags: grammar

> 青年が皆の手で地面に取り押さえられ、縄でぐるぐる巻きにされている**ところ**だった。

Does ところ here take on the meaning of "in the midst of doing"?

So this sentence would mean: "The boy was held down by everyone, and was being rolled up by a rope."?

Thanks!

Comment: Please write answers in the answer box :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[A bunch of questions about ところ](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/27541/a-bunch-of-questions-about-%e3%81%a8%e3%81%93%e3%82%8d)  seems a very good overview.

> 青年が皆の手で地面に取り押さえられ、縄でぐるぐる巻きにされているところだった。

- *Does ところ here mean "in the midst of doing"?* ------> Yes.

  "The young man was held down to the ground by everyone, and was being rolled up by a rope." ...

  -- as I (or another witness) arrived at the scene.

  -- just as I (or another witness) started watching the movie.

  -- when I (or another reader) opened up a random page in the book and started reading.

  Etc.