# Differing explanations of 〜ところを

Tags: particles, particle-を, passive-voice

My textbook has this example sentence:

> 試験中、となりの人の答えを見ている**ところを**先生に注意された。

The interpretation of this sentence hinges around ところを, and I'm not 100% sure what that means. The textbook simply indicates that it marks "while something is happening," and the ending particle (を in this case) matches whatever verb comes at the end.

If that's the case, then to me it looks like one of those "suffering passives" of the form "X suffered the teacher-warned-not-to-look-at-the-neighbour's-answers," where X is the subject. The gist of it being something like,

> "During the test, we were warned by the teacher to not look at our neighbours' answers."

However, in my dictionary of particles it says that ところを "Indicates that something unexpected has happened or is happening."

That definition doesn't seem to fit in this case, because it would leave the passive construction in a weird spot...

But I'm still not sure how my textbook's explanation of "while something is happening" fits in, exactly. It made me think that maybe the translation should be something like,

> "During the test, while I was looking at my neighbour's answers, I was warned by the teacher."

Which one of these is correct?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [A bunch of questions about ところ](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/27541/a-bunch-of-questions-about-%e3%81%a8%e3%81%93%e3%82%8d)

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/23738/5010

Comment: I don't see any instance of ところを in either of those

Comment: Then look at [this](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/18967/5010) and [this](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/27522/5010). This ところ by itself just means "scene (where I was looking at other person's answers)", which is the object of 注意する. 注意される is "sufferer passive" (i.e., the teacher warned me and I was negatively affected), but it has nothing to do with the usage of ところ here.

Comment: But now Seesawscene has said that the correct answer is my second interpretation, which, if the 注意される part is the sufferer passive, I would've thought to be incorrect. What it comes down to, I think, is: Was the speaker looking at his neighbour's answers while he was warned by the teacher? Or did the teacher just warn, in general, about not looking at one's neighbour's answers? It's a small difference, but I think it'd help me wrap my head around it if I can see the difference.

Comment: I'd translate it to "I was warned of how I was looking at my neighbour's answers by the teacher".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to 明鏡国語辞典:

> ところ 【所】
>   〘名詞〙
>   ⑥《連体修飾句を受け、時間的位置を規定する》 そのような**場面・状況・事態・場合**などの意。「家を出る**ところ**を見た」

The ところ in your example indicates the scene, situation, state, or occasion where something is happening or someone is doing something, and is often used in the form 「[人/物]が～～するところを/しているところを・・・」 for the English "SVOC" structure (like "I saw him crossing the street" "I heard her singing" etc.), eg:

> 佐藤さんは、私**が**授業中に居眠りしている**ところを**見た。
>   Sato-san saw me nodding during class.
>   山田君は、私**が**その部屋から出ていく**ところを**写真に撮った。
>   Yamada-kun photographed me leaving the room.

Turning them into Indirect Passive/間接受身:

> （私は、）授業中に居眠りしている**ところを**佐藤さんに見られた。
>   I was seen nodding during class by Sato-san.
>   （私は、）その部屋から出ていく**ところを**山田君に写真に撮られた。
>   I was photographed leaving the room by Yamada-kun.

<sub>Their Direct Passive/直接受身 versions would be:

（私が）授業中に居眠りしているところ**が**佐藤さんに見られた。

（私が）その部屋から出ていくところ**が**山田君に見られた。

... but the Indirect Passive versions would sound more natural in most cases.</sub>

---

Now, your sentence:

> 試験中、（私は）となりの人の答えを見ている**ところを**先生に注意された。

has the same structure as the two Indirect Passive examples above. Turning it back to active voice, you get:

> 試験中、先生は（私が）となりの人の答えを見ている**ところを**注意した。
>   *Literally*: The teacher warned me looking at my neighbor's answers during the test.

<sub>Its Direct Passive version would be:

試験中、（私が）となりの人の答えを見ているところ**が**先生に注意された。

... but this sounds pretty unnatural and uncommon.</sub>

注意する in this context means "warn against" or "warn/tell not to do", so your example practically means:

> "During the test, the teacher saw me looking at the answers of a student sitting next to me, and warned me not to do that. / told me to stop that."

Comment: Would it be okay to replace ところ with こと in these examples. I always get confused about this. If so, how would the meaning change?

Comment: @user3856370 I think 「授業中に居眠りしている**こと**を佐藤さんに見られた」「その部屋から出ていく**こと**を山田君に写真に撮られた」 sound unnatural. 「となりの人の答えを見ている**こと**を先生に注意された」 is okay but the meaning is a bit different. こと is like "the fact" so it's like "Teacher reproached me (not necessarily on the spot) for looking at~~."